# How to handle boundaries in conv/pool of conv-nets?

Tags: deep-learning, convolution

When convolution uses a kernel size of 4 and stride size of 4, meanwhile, the input size is only 10, it will be fail when trying to do third convolution operation on the boundary of input, so, should the input padded with zeros on boundary implicitly to avoid this problem? Is there any problem when I padded with other real numbers? Is it equals to increase the input size automatically?

Besides, if I expected to get a same size output feature map, usually kernel size of 3 and pad size of 1 can be used, but when kernel size is a odd number, how to decide the pad size on each side of input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the input must be padded with zeros to overcome the small input image size problem. To compute the output feature maps at each level use the following formula:

```
H_out = ( H_in + 2 x Padding_Height - Kernel_Height ) / Stride_Height + 1
W_out = (W_in + 2 x Padding_Width - Kernel_Width) / Stride_Width + 1
```

You may keep the padding in accordance with the above formula.